# Getting a Generator Function Returned as an Object Instead of Actually Invoking the Generator Function

Tags: javascript, node.js

For some reason I get [object Generator] returned instead of actually invoking the generator function itself.  So for     console.log("results: " + result); I get that I am getting back a generator function.

**gateway.js**

```
function _find(carId)
{
    var result = _carModel.find(carId);

    console.log("results: " + result);
    return result;
};
```

**carModel.js**

```
'use strict';

var pg = require('co-pg')(require('pg'));
var config = require('../../models/postgreSQL-Config');

var car = module.exports = {};

car.find = function *(id)
{
    var query = 'SELECT id, title, description, source FROM car WHERE id = ' + id;
        var poolConnection = yield pg.connectPromise(config.connection);

        var client = poolConnection[0];
        var done = poolConnection[1];

        var result = yield client.queryPromise(query);
        done();

        return result.rows;
};
```

[image]

UPDATE

I tried q first, and here's how I tried it:

**gateway.js**

```
function _find(carId)
{
    _carModel.find(carId)
    .then(function(result){
            console.log(result);
        return result;
        })
    .catch(function(error){
            console.log("promise error: " + error);
        })
    .done();
}
```

**carModel.js**

```
'use strict';

var Q = require('q');
var pg = require('co-pg')(require('pg'));
var config = require('../../models/postgreSQL-Config');

var car = module.exports = {};

car.find = Q.fbind(function *(id)
{
    console.log("GOT HERE!!!!!!");
    var query = 'SELECT id, title, description, source FROM car WHERE id = ' + id;
    var poolConnection = yield pg.connectPromise(config.connection);

    var client = poolConnection[0];
    var done = poolConnection[1];
    var result = yield client.queryPromise(query);
    done();

    console.log("RRRRRROOOOOOWWWS: " + result.rows);

    return result.rows;
});
```

it never hits my find method again, and I now get this in the terminal for the logging of the result that you see in my gateway function:

```
{ _invoke: [Function: invoke] }
{ _invoke: [Function: invoke] }
{ _invoke: [Function: invoke] }
{ _invoke: [Function: invoke] }
```

Comment: yield is only valid inside a generator function *

Comment: changed this up to be a new question, I have a diff problem.

Comment: you should use `Q.async`, not `Q.fbind`

Answer (score 1):

Invoking a generator function indeed returns a generator, not the result. You can step through the generator with `.next()`.

But it sounds like what you are looking for is wrapping your generator function with something like [co.wrap](https://github.com/tj/co) or [Q.async](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) (there are many others). They make your generator function return a Promise that resolves with the final result.

So you'd have this in `carModel.js` (with `co.wrap` added):

```
car.find = co.wrap(function *(id)
{
    // your code
});
```

And your `gateway.js` code would then become:

```
function _find(carId)
{
    return _carModel.find(carId)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log("results: " + result);
            return result;
        });
}
```

You can read more about it in [this blogpost](http://davidwalsh.name/async-generators).

Comment: do I need to start it with Q._carModel?  Thanks a lot for the reply

Comment: It would be `car.find = Q.async(function *(id) { /* ... */ });`. I've added how `carModel.js` could look to the answer above.

Comment: thanks.  Also notice though that co-pg already has promise functions built-in which I'm appearing to be using here.  So does it make sense to wrap that in yet another promise wrapper?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a generator function as a Promise, you need to wrap it with `co()`, as in the [co-pg examples](https://github.com/basicdays/co-pg). In your case, it is `co.wrap()`, because you want to return a function (for "later use"), as opposed to "plain" `co()`, which executes immediately.